# plotting single plot to figure with gratia package for model visualisation

Tags: r, data-visualization, mgcv

I am using Gavin Simpson's [gratia](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=gratia) package to plot my models (GAMs) as follows:

`draw(mod, scales = 'free', rug = NULL)`

The different plots get written to a single figure as follows (in an R Studio R notebook):

[image: figure containing 6 plots]

This quashes the output on my screen.

How can I get the draw function to output the different plots to different figures, like when I call the plot.gam function in mgcv:

`plot.gam(mod, shade = TRUE)`

which gives me a single plot per figure, e.g.

[image: figure with single plot]

I have looked in the gratia man pages, but haven't been able to find anything about it.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `select` argument to `draw.gam()`: https://gavinsimpson.github.io/gratia/reference/draw.gam.html

You can use `smooths(mod)` to return the names of the smooths that you want to plot:

```r
draw(mod, select = smooths(mod)[1])
```

will, for example plot the first smooth returned by `smooths()`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the select argument @Gavin! This works a treat now:

```for (i in 1:length(smooths(mod))) {                                        
  out <- draw(mod, select = i)  
  print(out)
}```

Comment: If I wanted to use the above loop to plot all terms (not just smooths but also parametric terms) how should I adjust the code?

I have been playing around with the arguments ```parametric = TRUE``` and ```terms = NULL``` but with no luck...

Comment: For the parametric terms, do `parametric_terms(....) %>% draw()`, replacing `....` with whatever arguments you need (if any). See `?parametric_terms`